# Ruby on Rails -- NameError '@' not allowed as an instance variable name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, instance-variables

I am fairly new to Ruby on Rails and have been stuck with this bug for quite sometime now. I am hoping that someone could give me some useful information to fix this bug. I have a feeling I am overlooking something trivial. Anyhow, I have included below my code that is drawing the Error (that is in the View) and also my code that is in my controller. While I have done my research before posting on here, I may have to put my instance variable in my controller -- however, I am unsure how that process goes and then how to call it from my View. I would appreciate any help! Thanks in advance :)

The error I get:

```
NameError in Search#indx
'@' is not allowed as an instance variable name
```

Here is my line of code that is drawing the error in my view (`apps/views/search/index.html.erb`):

```
<% @search = instance_variable_get("\@#{params[:model].to_s.downcase.pluralize}")%>
```

Here is my code in my controller (`apps/controllers/search_controller.rb`):

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @containers = Container.search(params[:q])
    @cpus = Cpu.search(params[:q])
    @disks = Disk.search(params[:q])
    @firmwares = Firmware.search(params[:q])
    @hardwares = Hardware.search(params[:q])
    @hosts = Host.search(params[:q])
    @interfaces = Interface.search(params[:q])
    @lans = Lan.search(params[:q])
    @licenses = License.search(params[:q])
    @rams = Memory.search(params[:q])
    @networks = Network.search(params[:q])
    @products = Product.search(params[:q])
    @roles = Role.search(params[:q])
    @sites = Site.search(params[:q])
    @vmpools = Vmpool.search(params[:q])
    @trackings = Tracking.search(params[:q])
  end

end
```

Comment: I believe you don't need to escape the at-sign: `"@#{...}"`

Comment: @August -- Tried that, it didn't change anything.

Comment: What's the param at that point?

Comment: my guess that `params[:model]` is nil and you are trying to get the value of `@`.  where are you setting `params[:model]` ?

Comment: Just FYI, doing this from `params[:model]` is potentially dangerous, since it could allow an attacker to pull arbitrary data out of your process.

Answer (score 9):

The problem is that `params[:model]` is `nil`, so you're essentially doing `instance_variable_get("@")`.

Take a look at the Rails log and see if the params you think are being received are actually being received.

**Edit:** The below is not directly related to the problem you're having (the previous two sentences explain why you're having that problem), but rather a suggestion for improving the way your code is organized.

Doing `instance_variable_get` in a view is a pretty bad code smell. Really, doing `instance_variable_get` at all is a code smell. There's almost certainly a better way to do what you're trying to do. For example:

```
def index
  query = search_params[:q]
  @search_results = {
    containers: Container.search(query),
    cpus:       Cpu.search(query),
    disks:      Disk.search(query),
    # ...
  }

  model = search_params[:model].to_s.downcase.pluralize # <-- this is also pretty smelly
  @search = @search_results[model]
end

private
def search_params
  params.require(:q, :model)
end
```

Then in your view you can just access `@search`.

Comment: The code above is an example meant to illustrate a better way to organize your code. It was not intended to be copy-and-pasted into your own code. You'll need to write your own code. And to reiterate, the NameError you originally saw is because `params[:model]` is `nil`, and the code above will not fix that. You need to figure out why your controller is not receiving the params you're expecting.

Comment: P.S. The syntax error suggest that you're using a very old version of Ruby that doesn't support this style of Hash initialization (i.e. `{ foo: 1 }` vs. `{ :foo => 1 }`). In 2014 you should be using Ruby 1.9.3 at a minimum.

Comment: I'm using Rails 4.1.1

Comment: Ruby is not the same thing as Ruby On Rails. Ruby is the programming language that the web framework Ruby On Rails is built with, and the programming language you write in when you build web applications with Ruby On Rails. The most recent stable version of Ruby is 2.1.5.

Comment: Yes, I do know that. My question was for Rails -- not Ruby. And, I am using Ruby 2.1.2. Thanks for your advice, Jordan. That will do.